# Implement function for trait implementor with dynamic and static dispatch

Tags: generics, rust

I want to have a function `foo` taking an instance of a type which implements a trait `A`. I always prefer to use generics in order to have static dispatch:

```
trait A {}

fn foo<T: A>(t: T) {}
```

---

However, this approach introduces some inflexibility, I can't pass a trait object like here:

```
trait A {}

fn foo(t: &A) {}
```

The thing is, sometimes I know the type and sometimes not. Is there a way to have both dynamic dispatch for trait objects and static dispatch for compile time known types while not implementing things twice?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That is indeed possible. One option is to explicitly implement `A` for its reference types:

```
impl<'a, T: A + ?Sized> A for &'a T {}
```

The argument becomes a trait object when `T = &A`, while still doing static dispatch for known implementors of `A`. The following code should now compile:

```
fn foo<T: A>(a: T) {}

struct MyA;
impl A for MyA {}

fn main() {
    foo(MyA{});
    foo(&MyA{});
    foo(&MyA{} as &A);
}
```

If you are willing to always pass a borrowed argument, you can also do this instead:

```
fn foo<T: A + ?Sized>(a: &T) {}
```

The argument becomes a trait object when `T = A`.

Comment: I'm not sure if I fully understand your `fn foo`. Isn't there always an implicit bound on `Sized`?

Comment: @torkleyy On the function argument, yes. That is ok because what we're providing is indeed always sized, in either case. The second function takes `&T`, which is sized, even if T is not.